# Why is Upstart not starting uWSGI?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upstart

I am trying to set up a django project on my VPS. I am trying to get a [uWSGI Emperor](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Emperor.html) to run and thus spawn vassals. I have set up all my config files as suggested by numerous websites including the uWSGI documentation. Yet when I run the file command

```
paul@example:/$ sudo service uwsgi start
```

I get the following:

```
start: Unknown job: uwsgi
```

I figured this was because Upstart couldn't recognize the uwsgi.conf file http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Upstart.html I have in /etc/init/. But after review I can not find anything wrong with it.

```
paul@example:/etc/init$ sudo vim uwsgi.conf
```

```
# Emperor uWSGI script

pre-start script
    logger "pre-start for uWSGI Emperor"
end script

post-start script
    logger "post-start for uWSGI Emperor"
end script

description "uWSGI Emperor"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

env LOGTO = /var/log/uwsgi.log

exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --master --die-on-term --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --logto $LOGTO
```

I also checked over my /etc/uwsgi/vassals files to make sure they were in working order. My only file right now is a mysite.ini file:

```
paul@example:/etc/uwsgi/vassals$ sudo vim mysite.ini
```

```
[uwsgi]
base = /home/paul/djprojs/mysite/
chdir = %(base)
master = true
threads = 20
socket = /tmp/sockets/%n.sock
home = /home/paul/.virtualenvs/dj
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%n.settings
module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()
```

But this looks okay to me also.

Finally, to test and see if uWSGI would run from the command line, I started it without Upstart. I ran

```
paul@exmaple/$ uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals
```

and it worked:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 1.9.13 (32bit) on [Sat Jul 27 19:23:43 2013] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 21 July 2013 03:35:50
os: Linux-3.2.0-24-virtual #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 12:51:49 UTC 2012
nodename: example.me
machine: i686
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 3922
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
*** starting uWSGI Emperor ***
*** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 6) ***
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from mysite.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 1.9.13 (32bit) on [Sat Jul 27 19:23:43 2013] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 21 July 2013 03:35:50
os: Linux-3.2.0-24-virtual #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 12:51:49 UTC 2012
nodename: example.me
machine: i686
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/vassals
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
your processes number limit is 3922
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/sockets/mysite.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:03:17)  [GCC 4.6.3]
Set PythonHome to /home/paul/.virtualenvs/dj
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x9bdb000
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 410112 bytes (400 KB) for 20 cores
*** Operational MODE: threaded ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x9bdb000 pid: 18213 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 18213)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 18214, cores: 20)
```

Then I was left without a bash prompt. The uWSGI cli shows all the server requests and doesn't return to let me type another command. I really feel like there must be a better way to do this (aka. using 'sudo service uwsgi start/restart') but I'm not sure how. I have looked into this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62812/why-isnt-my-upstart-service-starting-on-system-boot) but I'm not sure a different runlevel would solve the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is difficult to debug in upstart scripts. The problem is your line:

```
env LOGTO = /var/log/uwsgi.log
```

You can't have spaces around the '='. Just change to:

```
env LOGTO=/var/log/uwsgi.log
```

I'm afraid I wouldn't know if the uWSGI stuff was broken, but that should get your upstart job recognized at least.